# How can I flush the paragraph back to left and get normal paragraph?

Tags: paragraphs, text

I'm new to sharelatex and I dont know if this is an old question or not. I did add two figures with different positions but when I've written paragraph normally it's shifting to the right (only the first sentence. How can i fix this ? I just want it to start as usually near the marginal. The problem is at page 24 "at least two products.."
 Thank you! :)

Here is the code I've used for the pic:
`

```
\documentclass{article}        
\begin{document}
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{0.4\textwidth}
        \begin{center}
               \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{figure/resultat/TGADSC.jpg}
               \centering
               \caption[width=0.5\textwidth]{Signal result of TG and DSC for different transitions state}
               \label{fig:TGADSC}

        \end{center} 
        \end{wrapfigure} \\%http://www.americanpharmaceuticalreview.com/Featured-Articles/36776-Thermal-Analysis-A-Review-of-Techniques-and-Applications-in-the-Pharmaceutical-Sciences/


        This is an advantage when the sample deduce 
    (educe) phase changes whereat stoichiometry remains
     unchanged (same). Differential scanning calorimetry 
    (DSC) have similar function as DTA, except that the 
    temperature remains the same for the sample and the 
    reference. Which means that the heat will not be 
    distributed evenly for the sample and the reference 
    when changes is applied. Under endothermic process, 
    more heat will be required and negative signal will 
    display compared to the baseline and for exothermic 
    process is vice versa (motsattsen).
        %[1] Weller, M., Overton, T., Rourke, J., & 
    Armstrong, F. (2014). Inorganic chemistry. OUP 
    Oxford. Pages 262-263]

        \vspace{5mm} 
        Analyzing the data and how the mass of the 
    sample is affected by the heat could provide 
    information about the decomposition of the product,
     thermal stability, kinetics and the activation 
    energy of the decomposition. The general decomposition
     mechanism where the initial sample A break down at 
    certain temperature T and yield at least two products
     B and C.

 \end{document}       

`
```

[image]

Comment: welcome to the site but it is very hard to understand what input you had and what output you got, please try to make a small one page document that shows the problem and add the code to your question

Comment: Just google for parindent and parskip package.. If you already using parskip package (in your preamble or in your documentclass sty file) try \setlength\parindent{0pt}

Comment: Your image (which should be in this question not an answer) shows you are using wrapfig (which you had not mentioned!!) that has an optional argument to specify the number of lines that are indented to make space for the image.

Comment: show us what you have done so far with minimal working example.@ayema

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I will thank you for your comments :) it's not easy since its first time

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the number of shorter lines with an optional argument to `wrapfigure`, in the following example I choose 17, but as I don't have your image, you might have to adjust this number.

(Instead of manually doing `\vspace{5mm}`, I used `\setlength{\parskip}{5mm}`)

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig}
\setlength{\parskip}{5mm}
\begin{document}

\vspace*{10.5cm}

\begin{wrapfigure}[17]{l}{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{example-image-10x16}
  \caption[width=0.5\textwidth]{Signal result of TG and DSC for different transitions state}
  \label{fig:TGADSC}
\end{wrapfigure} 

This is an advantage when the sample deduce 
(educe) phase changes whereat stoichiometry remains
unchanged (same). Differential scanning calorimetry 
(DSC) have similar function as DTA, except that the 
temperature remains the same for the sample and the 
reference. Which means that the heat will not be 
distributed evenly for the sample and the reference 
when changes is applied. Under endothermic process, 
more heat will be required and negative signal will 
display compared to the baseline and for exothermic 
process is vice versa (motsattsen).
%[1] Weller, M., Overton, T., Rourke, J., & 
Armstrong, F. (2014). Inorganic chemistry. OUP 
Oxford. Pages 262-263]

Analyzing the data and how the mass of the 
sample is affected by the heat could provide 
information about the decomposition of the product,
thermal stability, kinetics and the activation 
energy of the decomposition. The general decomposition
mechanism where the initial sample A break down at 
certain temperature T and yield at least two products
B and C.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: there is some other photos that's not showing or moving to unwanted place. Do you know how i can fix it ? thank you :)

Comment: @ayema I'm terrible sorry, I already used up all my mind reading capabilities for this week. You need to ask a question that demonstrates your problem. Only then other people will be able to help you.